# Using dnsjava to query using java?

Tags: java, dns, dnsjava

I am trying to query using the google public dns server (8.8.8.8) to get the IP address of some known URL. However, it seems like I am not able to get that using the following code? I am using the dnsjava java library.  [This is my current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QryFC.png)

[The results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNbYy.png)

```
        Lookup lookup = new Lookup("stackoverflow.com", Type.NS);
        SimpleResolver resolver=new SimpleResolver("8.8.8.8");

        lookup.setDefaultResolver(resolver);
        lookup.setResolver(resolver);
        Record [] records = lookup.run();
        for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            Record  r = (Record ) records[i];
            System.out.println(r.getName()+","+r.getAdditionalName());
        }
    }
    catch (  Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        logger.error(ex.getMessage(),ex);
    }
```

Results:

```
stackoverflow.com.,ns-1033.awsdns-01.org.
stackoverflow.com.,ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.
stackoverflow.com.,ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.
stackoverflow.com.,ns-358.awsdns-44.com.
```

Comment: Yes, should be up now

Comment: The results also need to appear as text in your question.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557.

Comment: Changes have been made

Comment: Thank you.  I see that you also changed your code from using `Type.A` to `Type.NS`;  if you want IPv4 addresses, you want `Type.A`.  Or do you want to obtain the addresses of other name servers?

Comment: I want to use the public google dns at 8.8.8.8 and ask for the specific IP address of some URL

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need a DNS library just to look up an IP address.  You can simply [use JNDI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/jndi-dns.html):

```
Properties env = new Properties();
env.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
    "com.sun.jndi.dns.DnsContextFactory");
env.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "dns://8.8.8.8");

DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(env);
Attributes list = context.getAttributes("stackoverflow.com",
    new String[] { "A" });

NamingEnumeration<? extends Attribute> records = list.getAll();
while (records.hasMore()) {
    Attribute record = records.next();
    String name = record.get().toString();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

If you insist on using the dnsjava library, you need to use `Type.A` (as your code was originally doing, before your edit).

Looking at the [documentation for the Record class](https://static.javadoc.io/dnsjava/dnsjava/2.1.9/org/xbill/DNS/Record.html), notice the long list under **Direct Known Subclasses**.  You need to cast each Record to the appropriate subclass, which in this case is [ARecord](https://static.javadoc.io/dnsjava/dnsjava/2.1.9/org/xbill/DNS/ARecord.html).

Once you’ve done that cast, you have an additional method available, [getAddress](https://static.javadoc.io/dnsjava/dnsjava/2.1.9/org/xbill/DNS/ARecord.html#getAddress--):

```
for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    ARecord r = (ARecord) records[i];
    System.out.println(r.getName() + "," + r.getAdditionalName()
        + " => " + r.getAddress());
}
```